# Error: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

I try to do the function searchBook with java and jpa. I have 2 classes which are Media and Book. Book extends Media. And I keep the data in the different table. I try to select the data from the query below:

```
TypedQuery<Media> query = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT m.title, b.isbn, b.authors"
                        + " FROM Book b, Media m" + " WHERE b.isbn = :isbn"
                        + " OR lower(m.title) LIKE :title"
                        + " OR b.authors LIKE :authors", Media.class);
        query.setParameter("isbn", book.getisbn());
        query.setParameter("title", "%" + book.getTitle().toLowerCase()
                + "%");
        query.setParameter("authors", "%" + book.getAuthors() + "%");
        bookList = query.getResultList();
```

But I got the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query
>   with more than one return

This is the first time I use JPA. I can't find the the mistake.

Comment: m.title + b.isbn + b.author does NOT an instatiation of Media make.

Comment: how could i do? pls help

Comment: I can't see what you want, do you want Media's or Book's or something else that is not an entity?

Comment: actually, I do the same way as I do in the SQL. I want to select title, isbn and authors from the parameters which it could be isbn or title or authors.

Comment: You are going about this all wrong. If Book extends Media then you should model it that way in your entities. Please post the relevant entity code for both Book and Media. Posting the DDL for the tables would be nice too.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Without goind into details about how `Media` and `Book` should be modeled, I will at least explain why you get this exception.

You're doing:

```
em.createQuery(someJPQL, Media.class);
```

This means: create a query using `someJPQL`, and this query will return instances of the `Media` entity.

But your `JPQL` is:

```
SELECT m.title, b.isbn, b.authors ...
```

So the query does not return entities of type Media. It returns three fields, from two different entities. There is no way your JPA engine could magically create instances of Media from these 3 columns. A query would return instances of Media if it looked like this:

```
select m from Media m ...
```

Comment: I am still getting the error. My SQL looks like this: `SELECT NEW com.company.ui.EntityIDKey(c.companyId, c.name) FROM Company c WHERE c.companyId is not null and c.name is not null and length(trim(c.name)) > 0 order by c.name asc`. I am using a TypedQuery as follows: `List<EntityIDKey> companies = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql, EntityIDKey.class).getResultList();`

Comment: @WebUser don't hijack a question from 2?5 years ago. Ask your own question, and give all the details.

Comment: I wasn't trying to hijack the question. On the contrary, this thread was very relevant which is why I ended up trying your solution. I felt that if I was missing something and you could help find it, then it should help others.

Answer (score 71):

As a workaround, to get entity composed by other entity attributes, you can create it within query, providing constructor for it.

**Query :**

```
TypedQuery<Media> query = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW package_name.Media(m.title, b.isbn, b.authors)"
+ " FROM Book b, Media m" 
+ " WHERE b.isbn = :isbn"                         
+ " OR lower(m.title) LIKE :title"                         
+ " OR b.authors LIKE :authors", Media.class);
```

**Entity :**

```
public Media(String title, int isbn, String author){

    //-- Setting appropriate values
}
```

I have provided sample, change the datatypes of the constructor accordingly.

Comment: Actually a better approch is to use `JOIN FETCH` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39465150/1304830

Comment: This works but what if I've a list inside Media.class representing OneToMany mapping and I want to fetch for example only IDs of members of list?

Answer (score 11):

If you still want to use `TypedQuery` you can change the result type to `Object[]`.

```
List<Object[]> results = entityManager
    .createQuery("SELECT m.title, b.isbn, b.authors ...", Object[].class)
    .getResultList();
```

Each `Object[]` in the `List` represents a row of data. It contains the selected values for that row in the order in which they were selected in the query. Element 0 is the title, element 1 is the ISBN, and element 2 is the authors. You'll likely need to cast those values if you want to use them in a meaningful way. Since the field values come from two different tables, you could store them in some kind of container object.

```
List<MediaContainer> mediaList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Object[] row : results) {
    MediaContainer container = new MediaContainer();
    container.setTitle((String) row[0]);
    container.setIsbn((int) row[1]);
    container.setAuthors((String) row[2]);

    mediaList.add(container);
}
```

Comment: could you clarify a bit more how you would cast this? I take it that Object[] is a list of object fields. Can i just cast Object[] to the desired type? Or do i have to create a new instance of the desired type first and then set each field with the corresponding element in the Object[] array? Thank you

Comment: You can't cast an `Object[]` to a Hibernate entity. This particular result also returns values from two different tables (Media and Book) so there's not a single object those field values map to anyway. If you wanted to store the results in an object, you would have to loop through the results, cast each field value, then store the values in your new object. I updated my solution with an example of how you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

@WebUser instead of doing

```
List<EntityIDKey> companies = 
getEntityManager().createQuery(sql, EntityIDKey.class).getResultList();
```

Try this :

```
List<EntityIDKey> companies =
(List<EntityIDKey>)getEntityManager().createQuery(sql).getResultList();
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

if your are using Hibernate version < 4, you can meet this bug.

I go same problem with v3.5. Finally i had to use simple Query and cast each parameter manually

see other comments here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/axonframework/eUd1d4rotMY

Answer (score 0):

I... remove

> Media.class

of

> createQuery

because you return more **Entities** in this source **"SELECT m.title, b.isbn, b.authors"**

Ex.:

```
TypedQuery<Media> query = em.createQuery(
"SELECT m.title, b.isbn, b.authors"
+ " FROM Book b, Media m" + " WHERE b.isbn = :isbn"
+ " OR lower(m.title) LIKE :title"
+ " OR b.authors LIKE :authors");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by doing this kind of query:

```
em.createQuery( "SELECT m"
+ " FROM Book b, Media m" + " WHERE b.isbn = :isbn"
+ " OR lower(m.title) LIKE :title"
+ " OR b.authors LIKE :authors", Media.class);
```

but this works only if you need fields only from one of the requested tables