# foreach loop runtime error, cast from List<Object[]> to Object[]

Tags: java, arrays, jpa, swt, runtime-error

Upon trying to retrieve a table from database through JPA and fill it into the Table SWT widget (*`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table`*), I get a cast error while executing the following Java code:

```
EntityManager connection = DB.Connection().createEntityManager(); //the EntityManagerFactory
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = (TypedQuery<Object[]>) connection.createQuery("select t from Test t"); 
List<Object[]> tablelist = query.getResultList();
connection.close();

SWTtable.removeAll(); //clears all the elements in the table

for (Object[] row : tablelist) { //error on this line - java.lang.ClassCastException: {packagename}.Test cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    final TableItem item = new TableItem(SWTtable, SWT.None);
    item.setData(row[0]);
    item.setText(0, row[1].toString());
}
```

As seen above, this line `for (Object[] row : tablelist) {` returns an error of `java.lang.ClassCastException: {packagename}.Test cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

It seems that there is an error casting `tablelist` which is `List<Object[]>` to `Object[] row` in the foreach loop. I have tried various solutions, but cannot figure this out as I need to retain the option of `Object[]` array in order to have all the row elements at my disposal as items for the SWT table. Everything else works fine except this line of code. If it's set to `for (Object row : tablelist)`, so no array. Then there is no error, but I lose the array and thus lose the option to have all the elements at my disposal as items for the SWT table.

If this is a bad approach and you have other suggestions, please specify.

*Note: The SQL query, "select t from Test t" is just testing code. I will use a parmeter to specify which records I need later, so there will be more then one table here.*

Comment: It's `List<Test>` not `List<Object[]>`. So you need to fix `List<Object[]> tablelist = query.getResultList();` and then the loop.

Comment: Already tried that, same result.

Comment: @JoeBarr Did you also change the foreach loop which changing the above?

Comment: Yes, read the bellow comments, they asked the same thing. Only Object without an array works, Object[] array returns an error on runtime.

Comment: @JoeBarr: That's what the error message suggest. But just to be sure what the query is returning you can add a breakpoint at `connection.close();` and inspect the variable `tablelist`.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung I solved it, but now I have another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error like this:

```
"select t.id, t.first, t.second, t.last from Test t"
```

it was all in the SQL query. I had to define the attributes instead of just selecting all the attributes like this:

```
"select t from Test t"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, the exception is also telling you what is wrong. Test here is a JPA type, it is your typecast one line 2 that is incorrect. Your typecast is forcing a List< Test > to a List< Object[] >.

The javadoc `Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as a typed List.`

`item.setData` and `item.setText` should invoke the correct attribute accessor in `row`

```
EntityManager connection = DB.Connection().createEntityManager(); //the EntityManagerFactory
TypedQuery<Test> query = (TypedQuery<Test>) connection.createQuery("select t from Test t"); 
List<Test> tablelist = query.getResultList();
connection.close();

SWTtable.removeAll(); //clears all the elements in the table

for (Test row : tablelist) { //error on this line - java.lang.ClassCastException {packagename}.Test cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    final TableItem item = new TableItem(SWTtable, SWT.None);
    item.setData(row.getSomeAttribute());
    item.setText(0, row.getSomeOtherAttribute());
}
```

Comment: For me List<Object[]> tablelist = query.getResultList(); cannot remain an List<Object[]>. It says, change type of tablelist to List<Test> and if I change that I'm back to square one again. No objects and no array.

Comment: Ahh I missed one location when I edited your code, you are correct, it is a List<Test> which I mentioned in the original reply.

Comment: @Bhasker I managed to solve it, but now I have another error. Are you willing to help?

Comment: @JoeBarr why don't you just ask your question and I am sure someone will answer, feel free to ping me in a comment

Comment: @Bhasker Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343839/string-search-runtime-error-in-jpa-sql-query-jpql

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `tableList` contains a list of `Test` objects, not a list of Object arrays. That is why when you changed it to

```
for (Object row : tablelist)
```

the code worked.

Try changing

```
List<Object[]> tablelist = query.getResultList();
```

to

```
List<Test> tablelist = query.getResultList();
```

and change

```
for (Object[] row : tablelist) {
    ...
}
```

to

```
for (Test row : tablelist) {
    ...
}
```

You will have to change the code in the `for-loop` to work with the `Test`object instead of the `Object[]`. Without knowing what the `Test` object holds, it's hard for me to tell you how that would be done. But I would think the `Test` object should hold all the information that you are trying to retrieve from the array because that is how your information is being returned.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but then I lose the row array. The code was running like this, but now it has to be changed to an array of objects no matter what they are. They are tables, and you are correct about the information in table Test.

Comment: The only problem is for (Object[] row : tablelist), whatever else is changed works, except for this line. It only works as Object and not an array of the same.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area, but I think you would have to create one object that holds all the types (tables) you are returning. Did you look at this stackoverflow question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807496/error-cannot-create-typedquery-for-query-with-more-than-one-return

Comment: Actually yes. My code was setup like that, but I decided to cast it instead of sending a parameter class. It works the same, or doesn't in my case.