# String search runtime error in JPA SQL query (JPQL)

Tags: java, sql, jpa, runtime-error

When trying to retrieve a table from database through JPA and fill it into the Table SWT widget (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table`), I get a conversion error while executing the following Java code:

```
String SQL = String.format("select t.id, t.one, t.two from Test t where t.one like '%%s%' order by t.id",one); //variable one is defined as a parameter of the method (whole method not included here for simplicity)

//this is the code that uses the SQL variable above
EntityManager connection = DB.Connection().createEntityManager(); //the EntityManagerFactory
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = connection.createQuery(SQL, Object[].class); /*gives the same as cast (TypedQuery<Object[]>) */
List<Object[]> tablelist = query.getResultList();
connection.close();

SWTtable.removeAll(); //clears all the elements in the table

for (Object[] row : tablelist) {
    final TableItem item = new TableItem(SWTtable, SWT.None);
    item.setData(row[0]);
    item.setText(0, row[1].toString());
}
```

Error `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''` on runtime for line `String SQL = String.format("select t.id, t.one, t.two from Test p where p.one like '%%s%' order by p.id",one);`

The problem seams to be `'%%s%'` in the `String SQL` variable. I need to retain the `'%%s%'`, in order to search for all or one of the records selected with the query above.

- `'%%'` - returns all records, but with no String parameter
- `'%s'` - gives a specific record if the statement of the SQL query is
  correct

Everything else gives a problem, the string '%%s%' was not written by me, but I need to retain it or change it by maintaining the same results. The result I want is give all records, but upon receiving the String parameter return that specific record.

What could be the problem here is beyond my scope of JPA knowledge.

Comment: You may need to use `NameQuery` something like  `"select t.id, t.one, t.two from Test t where t.one like :one order by t.id` and then `namedQuery.setParameter("one", "%" + s + "%")`;

Comment: A NameQuery I can try, but a setParameter method returns only one specific record specified by that parameter.

Comment: setParameter just sets the parameter to the query.. something like `?` in `PreparedStatement`. Look at my answer, we have `:one` in query as a named parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked the `TypedQuery` API, you can set the parameters to it.

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = connection.createQuery("select t.id, t.one, t.two from Test t where t.one like :one order by t.id", Object[].class);
query.setParamter("one", "%" + s + "%");
List<Object[]> tablelist = query.getResultList();
```

Update:

It seems like those two conditions are seems separate like other answer suggests, you could do by generating your query something like

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select t.id, t.one, t.two from Test t "); 
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(s)) { 
    query.append(" where t.one like :one "); 
} 
query.append(" order by t.id");
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = connection.createQuery(query.toString());
```

Comment: Tried it and gives the exact same result, I don't even have to add the parameter I can just provide "%s%" in my query. After each search I now have to provide an extra space character in order for it to work, because of the last % used.

Comment: The above query gives you all the rows which has `s` in column `one`. Could you tell what kind of values an `s` can be and what all you are expecting from results?

Comment: Well like it says s is String. I provide a string namely "one", equal to the "one" attribute in table Test. As I also want to retrieve the rest of the characters not provided with the String "one", I put % in places that I need it in order to get all the attributes of the table Test and return a specific attribute name when complete parameter s in query is provided. Hope that is clear.

Comment: You were right, the first case works. Had a little bug in there after I modified it to your solution, fixed it and everything works as it should. Sorry about the inconvenience. I would up this a 1000 times if it allowed. +1 and answer accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would make these two queries it will perform better. Something like this:

```
public List<Object[]> collectOne( String param ) {
    TypedQuery<Object[]> query = connection.createQuery("select t.id, t.one, t.two from Test t where t.one like :one order by t.id", Object[].class);
    query.setParamter("one", "%" + param + "%");
    return query.getResultList();
}

public List<Object[]> collectAll() {
    TypedQuery<Object[]> query = connection.createQuery("select t.id, t.one, t.two from Test t order by t.id", Object[].class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Then you can always have the weird method that may or may not take an argument:

```
public List<Object[]> collectOneOrAll( String param ) {
    if ( param == null || param.isEmpty() )
        return collectAll();

    return collectOne( param );
}
```

Comment: Collect all not needed since I already have that separately when I want to retrieve everything, but this is not the case. This is a mix of collect all and s String specific word or letter. It needs to retrieve the rest of the letters of one or more attributes when s i provided. s can be only one letter, but it can also be a word. That word is finished by % in that query. The only thing which I cannot figure out is how that error spawns itself and what it means. There is no mention of it in the JPA/hibernate documentation.

Comment: You're not being clear. You need to give us the code for the test case that fails as well as the stack trace for the exception you are getting.