# JPA select query with multiple values

Tags: java, jpa, hql, entitymanager

```
select s.id,s.a.id,s.siteName from site  s where s.a.id=:b
```

I cannot execute this statement.

```
ERROR:
Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [com.a.b.entity.site]
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/4860__JPA_TypedQuery.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807496/error-cannot-create-typedquery-for-query-with-more-than-one-return

Comment: thank you.however i used native query and it worked.

Comment: I used native query for this. i stored the list of object as follows ..                                                                                        "List<Object[]> obj = Repository.findId(Id); "                                             and i tried to get the values but it didint work.                                                            "Site site;
for (Object[] object : obj) {
  site = new Site();                                                                     site.setSiteId(Integer.parseInt(object[0]))); }   .    is there any other way make an object  to integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround for your sub question:
use these to convert to integer  `new Integer((int) object[0])`